# Looking for a python library/framework for sound recognition

Tags: python, audio, machine-learning

I'm looking for a library or framework that is able to recognice a given sound (Not Speach).

For example I provide 3 ringtones and save them as A, B and C. When I play one of the ringtones my program is supposed to tell me which of the three it is.

Does something like this exist or do I need to use machine learning with tensorflow?